# How we apply continuity(hidden property) in differentiability as it is necessary?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous and one one function. Then $f'(x) \neq 0$ ( $f$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing). How to used continuity  in differentiability?

My attempt:
As we know that if f is one one then $x_1 \neq x_2$ implies $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$ so $f(x+h) - f(x) \neq 0$ for $x+h \neq x$ Then on dividing by $h$ on both sides and proceeding limit as $h \to 0$, we get $f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \neq 0$. I'm thinking that I'm not using continuity. But continuity is a necessary condition for differentiability. I'm confusing with these above information. Please help me.

Comment: The question is unclear. A continuous injective function is not necessarily differentiable.

Comment: @copper.hat A continuous injective function is monotone, isn't it? Thus differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: Yes, why are you asking?

Comment: (1) The claim as stated isn't true, if we interpret it as saying $f'(x)\neq0$ for all $x$ where $f$ is differentiable. Counterexample: $f(x)=x^3$. It's one-to-one, continuous, and even differentiable; and yet $f'(0)=0$. (2) In fact, you should clarify the question anyway, because it's not clear what it's asking. As pointed out in other comments above, $f$ doesn't even have to be differentiable (although yes, it has to be differentiable a.e.).

Comment: Your comment seemed to suggest the question might not be well posed. I was providing justification for how it might be true, at least almost everywhere